# Partial update the properties in database using merge-patch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

There a module that I'm working on which updates the user profile. However only the modified fields need to be updated in the database.

I'm using merge-patch for this. I have user mapped with phone_number as one-to-many with association table. However, if I'm trying to change modify any field in phone_number it's generating a new id every time.

Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> updateUser(String id, JsonMergePatch payload) {
    Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");
    try {
        //Getting the user based on the ID
        //Todo: replace with custom impl
        EosUser eosUser = eosUserRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiException("User not found"));
        //Converting the entity into the DTO
        UserDTO userDTO = UserMapper.INSTANCE.entityToDto(eosUser);
        //Using the patch to merge the modified properties with the DTO
        UserDTO mergedDTO = jsonPatch.patch(payload, userDTO, UserDTO.class);
        //Converting the DTO to the entity & saving
        eosUser = UserMapper.INSTANCE.dtoToEntity(mergedDTO);

        eosUserRepository.save(eosUser);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(mergedDTO, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

This is for updating the field.

```
public <T> T patch(JsonMergePatch patch, T targetBean, Class<T> beanClass) {

    JsonValue target = objectMapper.convertValue(targetBean, JsonValue.class);

    JsonValue patched = patch.apply(target);

    return objectMapper.convertValue(patched, beanClass);
}
```

userDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDTO extends BaseResponseDTO{
    private UUID id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String bio;
    private Boolean active;
    private Date dob;
    private String linkedInUrl;
    private List<EmailAddressDTO> emailAddresses;
    private List<PhoneNumbersDTO> phoneNumbers;
    private RoleDTO role;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class EmailAddressDTO {
        private UUID id;
        private String email;
        private String emailType;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class PhoneNumbersDTO {
        private UUID id;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String contactType;
    }
```

**I know that when the control comes to patch method, since there's no id field in the payload, the id value is set to null.**

I would like to know if there's another way using which I can modify this.

Appreciate your help.